# JMeter - How to prevent dashboard from showing every single thread's request - graphs contain 1000s of lines

Tags: multithreading, jmeter, dashboard

Basically, how do I configure either the report or my JMX so that graphs are much simpler and not showing all of the requests for every single thread like the below.

Clarification: I want to see all of the requests, but I don't want to see Request-1, Request-2, etc. Request-100 if there are 100 threads.  It gets very unwieldy even if the test has only a few requests, since they get multiplied by the number of threads.

I run from the JMX from the command-line headless.  I disabled all of the listeners in the JMX; there are only HTTP requests, variables, and cookie/cache/header managers.

[image]

I read the JMeter documentation on dashboard generation, but I didn't notice anything helpful.

In response to the comment, no, the request names do not have dynamic thread numbers in them.  Snapshot: [image]

I was using Transaction Controllers:[image]

Tried suggestion to use Apply Naming Policy, but that did not work.
The Response Times Over Time is still overcrowded with lines.

Comment: None do.    I'll post a picture as an example.

Comment: Show you  Transaction Controllers settings

Comment: I thought of the same thing, @user7294900.    They had been Transaction Controllers.  Maybe they should be Simple Controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using [Transaction Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) and want the only the transactions to appear in the [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) you need to apply naming policy to the controllers

[image]

This way the Transaction Controllers children will be treated like [Embedded Resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses/) and your charts will be more "clean"

Comment: Thanks as always @Dmitri T.  What if I use a Simple Controller instead?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this solution.  When I do this, it renames the requests, which I don't want it to do.  I'll explain in the OP.

Comment: I tried exactly what you suggested, and the Responses Over Time is still way overcrowded with data-points because of the threads.  Should I just break the JMX into smaller ones?